# How to get URL parameters names only and not values

Tags: javascript

There are hundreds of example out here showing how to get URL parameters but I couldn't find any to list ONLY parameters (variables) name and not values?

For example, if I have something like:

```
www.mydomain.com/filtres?makes=honda,mazda,jeep&models=crv,cx5,wamgler&years=2008
```

I want to get only `makes,models,years` and if URL change to

```
www.mydomain.com/filtres?makes=honda,mazda,jeep&models=crv,cx5,wamgler
```

should be like `makes,models`

or on

```
www.mydomain.com/filtres?makes=honda,mazda,jeep&models=crv,cx5,wamgler&years=2008,2010&city=vancouver
```

the out should be like `makes,models,years,city`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

Sample:

```js
const queryString = "?makes=honda,mazda,jeep&models=crv,cx5,wamgler&years=2008"

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);

console.log([...new URLSearchParams(urlParams).keys()]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log(
  [...new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).keys()].join(',')
);
```